ImportError for SORT module
I am following this tutorial for running YOLO v8 to detect and automatically identify number plates from a video. I am currently on, 30:02 time in the video, where he runs the code successfully.
This is my current code:
from ultralytics import YOLO
import cv2
from sort.sort import *
import string
import easyocr

mot_tracker = Sort()
results = {}

coco_model = YOLO('yolov8n.pt')
license_plate_detector = YOLO('/home/pi/Desktop/license_plate_detector.pt')

cap = cv2.VideoCapture('/home/pi/Desktop/carvid.mp4')

# Initialize the OCR reader
reader = easyocr.Reader(['en'], gpu=False)

# Mapping dictionaries for character conversion
dict_char_to_int = {'O': '0',
                    'I': '1',
                    'J': '3',
                    'A': '4',
                    'G': '6',
                    'S': '5'}

dict_int_to_char = {'0': 'O',
                    '1': 'I',
                    '3': 'J',
                    '4': 'A',
                    '6': 'G',
                    '5': 'S'}


def get_car(license_plate, vehicle_track_ids):
    x1, y1, x2, y2, score, class_id = license_plate

    foundIt = False
    for j in range(len(vehicle_track_ids)):
        xcar1, ycar1, xcar2, ycar2, car_id = vehicle_track_ids[j]

        if x1 > xcar1 and y1 > ycar1 and x2 < xcar2 and y2 < ycar2:
            car_indx = j
            foundIt = True
            break

    if foundIt:
        return vehicle_track_ids[car_indx]

    return -1, -1, -1, -1, -1


ret = True
frame_nmr = -1

vehicles = [2, 3, 5, 7]

while ret:
    frame_nmr+=1
    ret,frame = cap.read()
    if ret and frame_nmr < 10:
        pass
        
        detections = coco_model(frame)[0]
        detections_ = []
        
        for detection in detections.boxes.data.tolist():
            x1, y1, x2, y2, score, class_id = detection
            
            if int(class_id) in vehicles:
                detections_.append([x1,y1,x2,y2,score])
        
        track_ids = mot_tracker.update(np.asarray(detections_))
        
        license_plates = license_plate_detector(frame)[0]
        for license_plate in license_plates.boxes.data.tolist():
            x1, y1, x2, y2, score, class_id = license_plate

            xcar1, ycar1, xcar2, ycar2, carid = get_car(license_plate, track_ids)
            
            license_plate_crop = frame[int(y1):int(y2), int(x1): int(x2), :]
            
            license_plate_crop_gray = cv2.cvtColor(license_plate_crop, cv2.COLOUR_BGR2GRAY)
            _, license_plate_crop_thresh = cv2.threshold(license_plate_crop_gray, 64, 255, cv2.THRESH_BNARY_INV)
            
            cv2.imshow('original_crop', license_plate_crop)
            cv2.imshow('threshold', license_plate_crop_thresh)
            cv2.waitKey(0)


However, my code brings the following error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/yolotest.py", line 3, in <module>
    from sort.sort import *
  File "/home/pi/sort/sort.py", line 23, in <module>
    matplotlib.use('TkAgg')
  File "/home/pi/env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py", line 1255, in use
    plt.switch_backend(name)
  File "/home/pi/env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 415, in switch_backend
    module = backend_registry.load_backend_module(newbackend)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/pi/env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/registry.py", line 323, in load_backend_module
    return importlib.import_module(module_name)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/pi/env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_tkagg.py", line 1, in <module>
    from . import _backend_tk
  File "/home/pi/env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/_backend_tk.py", line 16, in <module>
    from PIL import Image, ImageTk
ImportError: cannot import name 'ImageTk' from 'PIL' (/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/PIL/__init__.py)

Note that I am using a Raspberry Pi 5 4 GB RAM running Raspberry Pi OS 64-bit. Along with that, all the system packages and libraries(including sort folder downloaded) are in a python virtual environment. Please help.

This question is similar to: cannot import name 'ImageTK' - python 3.5. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

sudo apt-get install python3-pil python3-pil.imagetk

This worked for my use case in the terminal.
